# Snowflake: query_history_by_user() does not yield expected result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake provides the QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER() function to actually see the queries from any user. I'm using this command for querying:

```
select * from table (
  <DATABASE>.<SCHEMA>.query_history_by_user(
    USER_NAME=>'myUser',
    END_TIME_RANGE_START=>to_timestamp_ltz('2021-11-24 06:00:00 -0100'),
    END_TIME_RANGE_END=>to_timestamp_ltz('2021-11-24 17:00:00 -0100'),
    RESULT_LIMIT=>100)
);
```

The problem is that this query does not yield any results. However, if I start the same query without the `USER_NAME=>'myUser'` statement - which is semantically the same, since the executing user is taken as a default - I do get the expected result. The result for a different user than mine (i.e. `USER_NAME=>'differentUser'`) is also empty. All queries are executed as `ACCOUNTADMIN`, so rights are presumably not the problem.

So the question is: why does the query work without any user provided but does not work with a user specified?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: `USER_NAME=>'"myUser"'` where myUser is `SELECT CURRENT_USER()`

Comment: How do I query for a different user than mine?

Comment: The idea here is to wrap user_name with `"` so it will be `USER_NAME=>'"differentUser"'`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! Would you mind to elaborate, why it has to be quoted that way?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it :-) ...I actually stumbled across the same paragraph but I didn't think it was relevant because my (real) usernames didn't include spaces or mixed-case characters. So I assumed that this is not the root of my problem. Either way: thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugest wrapping user name with `"`: `USER_NAME=>'differentUser'` => `USER_NAME=>'"differentUser"'`

[QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#arguments)

> A string specifying a user login name or CURRENT_USER. Only queries run by the specified user are returned. **Note that the login name must be enclosed in single quotes.**
>
> **Also, if the login name contains any spaces, mixed-case characters, or special characters, the name must be double-quoted within the single quotes (e.g. '"User 1"' vs 'user1').**